# How do I complete the Takes a Lickin' achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The *Takes a Lickin'* Act III challenge achievement says to "Get licked by 5 different Soul Rippers, Soul Lashers or Soul Devourers at once."

Trying to both survive kiting what small grouping of 3 of these that I find together is hard enough, especially without killing the little mooks, but even when I do get 5 or 6 of these things together, shortly before the effort kills me or I accidentally their faces, the achievement doesn't pop. What's worse is I have some equips which have damage on hit so they also tend to kill themselves along the way in the rare cases.

**What is the strategy or approach necessary to complete this achievement?** Is there a particular class/skill that would be helpful? Is there a location that this would be easier to do this in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get high enough in level go back to normal and make sure you dont have any armor one that deals damage when you are hit. You should be able to find enough and not take much damage. Stacking a little bit of armor wouldn't hurt. Also, you may be able to simultaneously drop and regain agro or cause mass stun to cause simultaneous attacks on you via character abilities. If you do not have a class with such abilities you may be able to use the town portal ability to enter the area and gather agro all at once, causing simultaneous attacks.

Comment: As I said in the question, even when I get them together, they don't lick me at once, thus not getting the achievement. Also, as I said, the damage on hit only causes problems in the *rare* cases.

Comment: What type of character are you using? If it has a mechanic you can abuse such as the demon hunters smoke screen when you come into view they should all agro and attack simultaneously. You could also try town portaling in, that might also simultaneously make all of them agro and attack.

Comment: If that's your answer, please edit it into your answer. While I'm using a Monk or Barb, the ideal answer would be one that covers how to do it with different classes, but if it works, even a class-specific strategy for any specific class would still be a good answer as long as it gets the achievement.

Comment: I found a sufficient supply of the right enemies in The Foundry Level 1 oddly enough. I made use of my monk's serenity skill to essentially artificially improve my armor as suggested. While trying to kite some of them together and scouting for more, I walked into a room which had several of these creatures to my surprise and as I walked right in, I drew all their aggro at once and got the achievement. So high armor and sudden aggro gain is the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Try using something that stuns/blinds enemies, or that makes you drop aggro, then be in range for them to turn and attack you once when they get out of stun

For example, a Monk can use [Blinding Flash](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/blinding-flash) to stun all enemies in the area without damaging them, and then just hope at least 5 decide to do their tongue attack once they've recovered

I'm not as familiar with other classes, however I believe the Barbarian's [Ground Stomp](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/ground-stomp) will also stun, the Wizard's [Teleport](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/teleport) will let you teleport into a group so they'll all turn and hit you at once, and the Demon Hunter's [Smoke Screen](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen) or the Witch Doctor's [Spirit Walk](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/spirit-walk) will drop aggro, which should make everyone turn and hit you simultaneously once you appear again.

I believe the dungeons below Bastions Keep is the best place for this (can't remember what it's called, but seen at least 2 other people get their achievement there while going through with them)

Comment: ...Uh...Act 3 is the *only* place for this. It's an Act 3 achievement.

Comment: @skovacs1 lol ok, didn't notice that. Edited answer to remove Act III from the location :)

Comment: @skovacs1 Updated my answer to include strategies for other classes  as well :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me to do this was to find an elite pack of Soul Rippers that are Illusionist.  When they spawn their illusions, they often all lick you at once, and all of the illusions count as a separate monster.

I did it in the second part of Act 3 when you descend down the crater to fight Azmodan.  Along the way you often find elite packs of Soul Rippers, and the levels are open enough so that they illusions can spawn all around you and lick you at once.

It probably helps a lot to be a melee class that would be standing in the middle of the pack of illusions.  When I got the achievement, I was going through Act 3 in Hell mode as a Barbarian in a party with another Barbarian and a Monk.  We encountered two elite packs of Soul Rippers, both who were Illusionist, and everyone in the party got this achievement without even trying for it.  In comparison, it would have been harder to get this achievement if I was playing my wizard, because I probably couldn't survive long enough in the middle of a pack of Soul Rippers to get it.  One idea might be to just diamond skin and run into the center of a pack.

Answer (score 2):

I got this on my Barbarian by having 0 thorns damage, finding 5 of the Soul Rippers on Normal, then went AFK. Had the achievement when I was back :)

Comment: LOL. That's how I'm going to do it tonight during dinner! :D

Answer (score 1):

I rallied up about 7 of these things in Keep depths level 2, as a demon hunter. I'd equip my weapon to Impale targets that were not the lickers themselves, to get fodder out of the way, and then try to round them up in to a room. I'd use non-lethal caltrops +vault to essentially leave them in a room to go find more. When I had finally rounded up 7 all in one place, I just sat in a corner, and they did the rest. It was difficult because dodge chance can get in the way, so I had to equip some of the level 22 gear I was finding in the dungeon it self- and I made sure none of it had dex.

All in all, my dodge was down to 15.1%, and I only equipped my weapon to impale skeletons and the like. Hope this helps!